# How to calculate the mean, max, and min accuracy of an RF model for 20 iterations using Python for-loop? just want what shuols add to this code please

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, average

Please any one help me to add iteration by using (for loop) in python, (20 iterate of accuracy and time in second) and then find the std (standard devision) ,max value , min value for accuracy and time.
Thanks a lot

I tried to make this iteration but the cod work without read it

```
forest1 = RandomForestClassifier()
start_time = time.time()

forest1.fit(X_train[selected_PSO], y_train)

end_time = time.time()

execution_time_rfcpso = end_time - start_time
print("Time taken for training:", execution_time_rfcpso, "seconds")
y_pred = forest1.predict(X_test_selected)
accuracy_rfcpso = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('Accuracy:', accuracy_rfcpso)
```